# Wildcard Capture Rules Puzzler

Tags: java, generics

I am making some changes to a framework which has several generics classes, the two key ones being a self-typed `Holder<H extends Holder<H, T>, T>`, and a `HolderFactory<H extends Holder<H, T>, T>` which, you guess it, takes in `<T>` to make `<H>`.  I'm running into an issue I can't quite fathom.

There are two static methods I need to cooperate. One is essentially:

```
public static <T> HolderFactory<?, T> makeSpecialHolderFactory(Class<T> clazz);
```

The other is essentially:

```
public static <H extends Holder<H, T>, T> void process(HolderFactory<H, T> factory);
```

There are many details I'm omitting which necessitate this hierarchy, but the details above are sufficient to reproduce the error.  The following line does not compile:

```
static <T> void puzzler(Class<T> clazz) {
  process(makeSpecialHolderFactory(clazz));
}
```

The errors are essentially:

- The method `process(HolderFactory<H,T>)` is not applicable for the arguments `(HolderFactory<?,T>)`
- Type mismatch: cannot convert from `HolderFactory<capture#1-of ?,T>` to `HolderFactory<H,T>`

But this is bollocks, because if I specify `<T>` explicitly on the method call, or do any number of other things, everything's fine!

```
process(UtilityClass.<T>makeSpecialHolderFactory(clazz));  // Compiles fine
```

***Question:*** Why does the compiler not recognize that `capture#1` satisfies the type bounds of `Holder` when it must by the very class definition of `HolderFactory`? And why does it only complain about this when `<T>` isn't explicitly specified on the method call, which should make no difference, since `<T>` can by fully inferred from the argument?

For completeness, here's a clean, compileable example:

```
public class GenericsPuzzler {
    interface Holder<H extends Holder<H, T>, T> {}
    interface HolderFactory<H extends Holder<H, T>, T> {}

    static <T> HolderFactory<?, T> factory(Class<T> clazz) {
        return null;
    }
    static <T> HolderFactory<?, T> factory2() {
        return null;
    }
    static <T> HolderFactory<?, T> factory3(T thing) {
        return null;
    }

    public static <H extends Holder<H, T>, T> void process(HolderFactory<H, T> factory) {}

    public static <T> void puzzler(Class<T> clazz, T thing) {
        // Compile Errors
        process(GenericsPuzzler.factory(clazz));
        process(GenericsPuzzler.factory3(thing));

        // Everything below works
        process(GenericsPuzzler.<T>factory(clazz));
        process(GenericsPuzzler.<T>factory2());
        process(GenericsPuzzler.<T>factory3(thing));
        process((HolderFactory<?, T>) GenericsPuzzler.factory(clazz));
        process((HolderFactory<?, T>) GenericsPuzzler.factory2());  // Warning
        process((HolderFactory<?, T>) GenericsPuzzler.factory3(thing));
        HolderFactory<?, T> factory = null;
        process(factory);  // Works
    }
}
```

I'm using jre1.8.0_11.

Comment: Using the wildcard `?` means that you create a "read only" generic object - you can see this with `List<? extends Foo>`. This is because, in the list example, `list.add` takes a `? extends Foo` and the way generics are designed **there is no `class` that has a type `? extends Foo`** - no even `Foo` itself. So your use of the wildcard is wrong in this instance.

Comment: If you changed process to require `? extends HolderFactory<H, T>` then this would solve your problem - but might well create others further down the hierarchy.  Why not let the compiler infer `H` rather than using `?`?

Comment: `process` does require `? extends HolderFactory<H, T>`, that's the type of the argument.  Same as a `List<T>` accepts `? extends T` for `add()`.  I am letting the compiler infer `H` for `process`, but I can't let it do that for `makeSpecialHolderFactory` because it's part of the return type.  I want to use `?` there because the actual type of `H` is meant to be an implementation detail, but this issue prevents me from doing that.

Comment: And you have just answered your own question! You cannot _tell_ the compiler the type because you yourself do not know it. Therefore the compiler cannot guarantee type safety (exactly what `? extends ...` means). If you change that to `H` then it will be inferred by the from the caller's required type, but that may not be what you want either. Basically you are _telling_ the compiler that you do not know what the type is and the compiler is acting in that information. You need to either 1) change `? extends` to a type than _can_ be inferred `H extends ...`  (continued)

Comment: (continued) or cast the returned value, thereby overriding the compiler's guarantee of type safety explicitly.

Comment: I'm not sure we're on the same page.  If you think you have a solution, can you post the exact edits you would make to the sample for it to compile?  Changing '?' to a generic 'H' is nonsensical for `makeSpecialHolderFactory` because such a method can't be implemented, there's no way to instantiate *any* H the caller asks for.  Your argument about `?` and type safety is invalid because simply *storing the result of makeSpecialHolderFactory in a temp variable*, with no compiler warnings, and then using that variable is sufficient to make the code compile.  The compiler is not being consistent.

Comment: Type inference only works in simple cases. There are many situations in which you have to explicitly provide an explicit type witness or it won't work. This is probably one of them.